# Poner icono y tooltip en el tbody

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-admin

He creado una columna con valores de 2 columnas existentes.
Y quiero que en el segundo valor que es un booleano me aparezca el valor con una imagen y un tooltip. ¿Cómo se haría?

admin.py

```
def estado(self, obj):
    return format_html("<b>{}</b> {}", mark_safe(self.estado(obj)), obj.excluido)
```

(El primer valor que he puesto "self.estado(obj)" es una url)
Si yo pusiera en el list_display el 'excluido' me pondría una imagen o otra de pendiendo si es True o False. Y esa es la imagen o icono que quiero que me aparezca.